# White space appears below sticky footer, only in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, sticky-footer

I have a problem when trying to implement a css sticky footer on my page, using [Ryan Fait's technique](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

I have followed his instructions to a T. The footer displays exactly as expected when applied to an `.html` file. However, I am using PHP to generate my web pages, and for some reason a fair amount of white space appears below the footer, only when the style is applied to PHP.

I looked at the source in Firebug and the `<div class="wrapper">` has extra height in the PHP version, which is *not* present in the html alone.

I've formatted my html according to instructions and have the following structure, nested within `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Content in here -->
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <!-- Footer in here -->
</div>
```

Are there any known issues with extra white space below sticky footer elements **only in php** and if so, how could I resolve this?

Comment: can you show a bit of css applied to `body` and all these classes ?

Comment: please post your php version of the code

Comment: Is there any textarea present in your code?

Comment: Do you perform some includes? If so, pay attention to the encoding: UTF8 without BOM is suitable. The BOM can create troubles. See http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php#problems

Comment: @prava No there is no textarea. There is a table in the content div with text inputs with the code from [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625648/validate-and-submit-multiple-input-fields-in-array-in-php-rank-order).

Comment: @NicolasHenrard I have one include for a processing script on passing form validation checks. I checked the encoding in Notepad++ and it's set to UTF-8 without BOM for both files.